# How to include multiple input tensor in keras.model.fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am a keras rookie and I need some help in working with keras after many days struggling at this problem. Please ask for further information if there is any ambiguity.

Currently, I am trying to modify the code from [a link](https://github.com/lukaszbinden/pediatric-bone-age-prediction/blob/master/src/models/RSNA16BitNet.py/).According to their network model, there are 2 input tensors expected. Now I have trouble including 2 input tensors into the source code provided by them.

Function Boneage_prediction_model() initiates a model of 2 input tensors.

```py
def Boneage_prediction_model():
    i1 = Input(shape=(500, 500, 1), name='input_img') # the 1st input tensor
    i2 = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_gender')       # the 2nd input tensor
    ... ...
    model = Model(inputs=(i1, i2), outputs=o)         # define model input 
                                                        with both i1 and i2
... ... 

#using model.fit_generator to instantiate
# datagen is initiated by keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator
# img_train is the 1st network input, and boneage_train is the training label
# gender_train is the 2nd network input  
model.fit_generator(
                     (datagen.flow(img_train, boneage_train, batch_size=10), 
                      gender_train),
                      ... ...
                    )
```

I tried many ways to combine the two (datagen.flow(img_train, boneage_train, batch_size=10) and gender_train) as stated above, but it failed and kept reporting errors 
 such as the following,

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[-0.26078433],
         [-0.26078433],
         [-0.26078433],
         ...,
         [-0.26078433],
         [-0.26078433],
         [-0.26078433]],
        [[-0.26078433],
         [-0.26...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failure either blindly to simply combine the 2 inputs, or as another contributor suggested, to use a dictionary to map the multiple inputs, I realized it seems to be the problem of *datagen.flow* which keeps me from combining a image tensor input and a categorical tensor input. *datagen.flow* is initiated by *keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator* with the goal of preprocessing the input images. Therefore chances are that it is inappropriate to combine the 2 inputs inside *datagen.flow*. Additionally, fit_generator seems to expect an input of generator type, and what I did as proposed in my question is wrong, though I do not fully understand the mechanism of this function.

As I looked up carefully in other codes written by [the team](https://github.com/lukaszbinden/pediatric-bone-age-prediction/blob/master/src/models/RSNA16BitNetServer.py), I learned that I need to write a generator to combine the two. The solution is as following,

```
def combined_generators(image_generator, gender_data, batch_size):
    gender_generator = cycle(batch(gender_data, batch_size))
    while True:
        nextImage = next(image_generator)
        nextGender = next(gender_generator)
        assert len(nextImage[0]) == len(nextGender)
        yield [nextImage[0], nextGender], nextImage[1]


def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]


train_gen_wrapper = combined_generators(train_gen_boneage, train_df_boneage['male'], BATCH_SIZE_TRAIN)

model.fit_generator(train_gen_wrapper, ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have two inputs for one network and have one label for the combined output. In the official [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator) for the `fit_generator` there is an example with multiple inputs.

Using a dictionary to map the multiple inputs would result in:

```py
model.fit_generator(
                    datagen.flow({'input_img':img_train, 'input_gender':gender_train}, boneage_train, batch_size=10),
                      ... 
                    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to be an elegant solution, but I still failed to run the code based on your advice. It reported the lengths of the images tensor and the labels do not match. I suppose this problem results from *datagen.flow*. I learn an another way to use *fit_generator* from you anyway, so thanks!